# torch gather 3D tensor with 2D tensor as "gather map"

Tags: python, pytorch

For the given tensors of dimensions 
`data.shape [B,N,F]` and `indices.shape [N,K]`,
Where `K` are the indices of the "neighborhood" of each point N,
 is there a simple method of gathering the neighbors such that `output.shape [B,N,K,F]` ?

```
data = [[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],[[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[2,3,4]] # Shape 2,3,3
indices = [[1,2],[1,0],[0,0]] # Shape 3,2

output = [
         [[[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],[[2,3,4],[1,2,3]],[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]],
         [[[6,7,8],[2,3,4]],[[6,7,8],[3,4,5]],[[3,4,5],[3,4,5]]]
         ]
```

For example, The first point in each batch "relates" to points `[1,2]`, Thus `output[0][0] = [[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]` Which are points `1,2` in the first batch of the input.

My attempt:

```
batched_indices = indices.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(-1).repeat(batch_size,1,1,feature_size)
data_neighs = data.unsqueeze(2).repeat(1,1,num_neighs,1)
output = torch.gather(data_neighs,batched_indices,dim=1)
```

Comment: Just to be sure to understand correctly, can you show how you would do it in a naïve `for`-loop based approach ?